# Chrome (or any) dev tools console is not displaying Javascript "output" (console.log) using VS Code

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools, visual-studio-extensions

I am using (on a MAC) VS Code with the Live Server extension and Chrome with the developer tools open.

What I am expecting to see is a "Live" console (console.log) readout (in the CONSOLE tab) of the result of my code when I do a SAVE in VS Code, but this is not happening. I can see my .js file and .html files in the SOURCES tab and they update dynamically as I make changes in VS Code, so *something* is working, just not the console.

I have tried this with Chrome Canary, Firefox Developer Edition and Edge, on both MAC and Windows 10 and the result is always the same - the console doesn't display anything. Since this is failing on every browser and operating system I try, my sense is that I'm missing something fundamental.

To be clear, Live Server is working perfectly except for the console. Perhaps it's something in my environment.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Perhaps a dumb question, but is your js included in your html file?

Comment: What happens if you set a breakpoint at 2 or 4?

Comment: Good question @mykaf. Yes the .js file is referenced / in the .html file

Comment: Please include the code where you are referencing the js.

Comment: I'm not sure I know what you mean @isherwood. Do you mean adding breakpoints in the sources tab?  I'm kind of a newb, if it wasn't obvious. ;)

Comment: Here is the code @mykaf  `<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>TEST</title>
    <script> src="script2.js"</script>
</head>
<body>
    TESTING 1, 2, 3
</body>
</html>`

Comment: Should be `<script src="script2.js"></script>`

Comment: Oh my @Konrad, you nailed it! Thank you so much. I knew it would be some kind of dumb typo/syntax thing on my part. Cheers!

Comment: @FredMaher Hi Fred, I posted an answer, I hope it explains the situation well. If it could explain the situation you encountered, could you please [mark it as the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) to end this question? This will help others who encounter a similar issue and seek a solution. If you want to post your own answer, you could also post it and mark it as the answer. :)

Comment: @FredMaher — you can just hit the delete option in your question. Trivial problems caused by typos aren’t useful to other people (they’ll never find them by searching) so should be closed instead of archived.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Konrad mentioned, the issue on your side comes from the wrong usage of the  tag.

It should includes a `src` attribute, but the attribute is not properly set. Instead, the `src` attribute is surrounded by the opening and closing script tags, which is not a valid way to include an external JavaScript file.

In this incorrect code you showed, the entire `<script> src="script2.js"</script>` will be treated as plain text content within the HTML document. It will not be recognized as an external JavaScript file reference, and the content inside `script2.js` will not be executed as JavaScript.

To properly include an external JavaScript file, you should use the correct syntax, as follows:

```html
<script src="script2.js"></script>
```

This way, the browser will recognize it as an external script and attempt to load and execute the JavaScript code from the `script2.js` file.